# Keystroke listeners doesn't working properly from inside terminal (ubuntu 22, python 3)

Tags: python, keyboard, console-application

I'm trying many pynput keyboard examples to capture key strokes but anything works from inside the terminal.

Ex:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

    
def pressed(key):
    print('Pressed:',key)

def released(key):
    print('Released:',key)
    if key == Key.enter:
        # Stop detecting when enter key is pressed
        return False

# Below loop for Detcting keys runs until enter key is pressed
with Listener(on_press=pressed, on_release=released) as detector:
detector.join()
```

Snippets like this (also other complex ones) only detect keystrokes when I'm focus on other windows but need to capture the keystrokes from inside the terminal to give functionality to my console apps.

Anyone experienced the same?

Thank you